# How can I define express middleware for all routes

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to define one global middleware which will work for all routes of my app. I tried some ways but still got some issues.

```
var _gMDLW = function (req, res, next) {
  if(req.route) console.log('Called route ', req.route.path);
  next();
}

// Working fine and result on _gMDLW is /route1
app.get('/route1', _gMDLW, function (req, res, next) { return res.sendStatus(200); })


var globalRouter = new express.Router()

// Working fine and result on _gMDLW is /view
globalRouter.route('/view')
  .get(_gMDLW, function (req, res, next) { return res.sendStatus(200);})
app.use(globalRouter);
```

But problem is here

```
// Error in _gMDLW and getting /list instead of /items/list
var itemRouter = new express.Router()
itemRouter.route('/list')
  .get(_gMDLW, function (req, res, next) { return res.sendStatus(200);})
app.use('/items', itemRouter)
```

Second Question is is there any way to define/add `_gMDLW` inside `app` instead of adding in each route something like `app.use(_gMDLW)` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `app.all()` to resolve this issue

### Example

```
app.all('*', _gMDLW);

function _gMDLW(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path == '/') return next();// redirect to homepage for guest

    next();//authenticated user
}
```

You can modify it as your requirement

Comment: It is not only about call  `_gMDLW` before each call. I also need `req.route.path` so that I can get this idea about which route/api is called.And in this case i am always getting `*` as path.

Comment: app.all('*') mean it just invoke on every call and you can get path from req.path

Comment: i am getting req.path which is `*` always. What will i do with it ?

Comment: make sure this line must be above of all the routes, it's working fine for me

Comment: Thank you for your time. This solution is still not working because in case of `/route1/:rid/view/:infoid` I will always get `/route1/r1/view/info1` How can I get the idea which rout is this now ?